# iOS EventKit problems?

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, icloud, eventkit

I wish to add calendar events to a specific calendar (based on user choise).

My problem is that I am unable to list iCloud and Gmail calendars that are on the device.

I do not wish to list the Birthday calendar or Subscription calendars, since they are un-editable...

Right now I am only using the EKCalendarTypeLocal calendar type, but is there a way to also display iCloud and Gmail calendars?